# Android translucent status bar on samsung devices

Tags: android

So, another day, another problem: I want to get the translucent background on my app, the code works on another devices with both Marshmallow and Lollipop, but don't on my Samsung A5 2016 (Android 5.1.1 - API 22)... Here is a print:

[image: Printscreen showing the problem]

And here is the code:

**main_activity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.net.beno.pantoid.activities.main.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**v21/styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.BrandedLaunch" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/branded_bg</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I noticed that there are apps where this behavior works as intended, like on Play Store and Prisma...

Comment: Samsung specific behaviors. I fixed it by not flagging windowsTranslucentStatus. But instead set status bar color and on onCreate adding WINDOWS_FULLSCREEN flag